# Smoothly watching through TurtleBot Kinect camera

Tags: kinect, rviz, turtlebot, ros-electric

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It seems that the visualization tools such as rviz take a lot of computational resources. Actually I just want to watch through the Kinect camera (see what TurtleBot sees) but I don't need other fancy 3d simulation stuff. Is there any simple, high performance package that can do this? Thank you very much.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/57073/smoothly-watching-through-turtlebot-kinect-camera/) by [Chik](https://answers.ros.org/users/3814/chik/) on ROS Answers with karma: 229 on 2013-03-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you only want to see the camera image, use image_view, e.g.:

`rosrun image_view image_view image:=/camera/rgb/image`

---

Originally posted by [dgossow](https://answers.ros.org/users/1564/dgossow/) with karma: 1444 on 2013-03-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you need a simple 3D viewer of the pointcloud produced by the kinect, I'd go with the PCL. They provide a lightweight viewer as well as a full-featured one:

- simple CloudViewer: http://www.pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/cloud_viewer.php
- PCL Visualizer: http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/pcl_visualizer.php

Just register a callback that accesses the XYZRGB-Pointcloud of the kinect and, inside the callback, provide the pointcloud to the viewer.

---

Originally posted by [Philip](https://answers.ros.org/users/4292/philip/) with karma: 990 on 2013-03-04

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1